# How can a Rust application send a cloud-to-device message to the IoTHub intended to reach a device?

Tags: azure, rust, azure-iot-hub

I am building an MQTT-based Rust application that sends a message to the IoTHub so that this is forwarded to a target device which listens to cloud-to-device messages.

The target device "myDev" is subscribed to the topic `devices/myDev/messages/devicebound/#` and it can receive messages from the IoTHub interface ("Message to Device", on the Azure Portal).

The examples I have found to achieve this in other programming languages use the Azure IoT SDK, which has a client service. See for instance the example for Java: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-c2d#send-a-cloud-to-device-message

The problem is that there is really no official Azure IoT SDK for Rust. I could only find this project https://github.com/damienpontifex/azure-iot-sdk-rs which I cannot use because it has a dependency with Tokio > 1.x and I have to stick for now with Tokio 0.x.

However, I can imagine that sending a cloud-to-device message to IoTHub must be somehow doable.
Required Information is probably: device_id, body and the properties, which are the fields available in the interface.

But I haven't found further details anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is no official SDK - but there are some other implementations you can have a look at it, like [this one](https://docs.rs/azure_iot_sdk/0.7.1/azure_iot_sdk/) with the following example:

```
use tokio::time;
use azure_iot_sdk::{IoTHubClient, DeviceKeyTokenSource, Message};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> azure_iot_sdk::Result<()> {
    let iothub_hostname = "iothubname.azure-devices.net";
    let device_id = "MyDeviceId";
    let token_source = DeviceKeyTokenSource::new(
        iothub_hostname,
        device_id,
        "TheAccessKey",
    ).unwrap();

    let mut client =
        IoTHubClient::new(iothub_hostname, device_id.into(), token_source).await?;

    let mut interval = time::interval(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    let mut count: u32 = 0;

    loop {
        interval.tick().await;

        let msg = Message::builder()
            .set_body(format!("Message #{}", count).as_bytes().to_vec())
            .set_message_id(format!("{}-t", count))
            .build();

        client.send_message(msg).await?;

        count += 1;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Alternatively, If Rust is not a hard requirement, at least end-to-end, maybe you can have an independent service that deals with the operations with IoT Hub, and have it called from your Rust code as a normal REST service.

Comment: Thank you. I gave it a try but I cannot use it due to the dependency of the sdk of using Tokio >= 1.x (I am using 0.x). I will update my question.